# What is the set of fixed point under the action of T in this example

Tags: linear-algebra, group-actions

Let $M= \lbrace g\lambda g^{-1} , $ $ g \in SU(3)\rbrace $ such that $\lambda = diag(i\lambda_1, i\lambda_2, i\lambda_3) $, $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2 > \lambda_3 .$

Let  $T= \lbrace diag (t,t,t') , t,t' \in U(1)\rbrace$ be the subgroup of SU(3) of diagonal matrices such that the first and the second entries are equal. Consider the action of T on M by conjugation.

What is the set $M^T=\lbrace m \in M , t.m=m \forall t \in T\rbrace $ of fixed point in $ M $ under the action of T on M ?

I greatly appreciate any help in this.

Comment: Please note that askers are expected to provide context for their posts, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/81360). For example, it would be helpful if you could answer any of the following by editing your post accordingly. Where did you encounter this problem? What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Actually, the fact that the fixed point set $ M^T$ is  finite was used in a problem in equivariant cohomology to calculate the integral of an equivariant differential form. But i'm not able  to figure out  what is the elements of this set . My thoughts so far is that perhaps this has to do with the weyl group of SU(3) and with permutations !

Comment: It is not true that $M^T$ is finite, maybe you're missing some details of the question. In any case, are you able to characterize the elements of the set $M$?

Comment: The only information I have about M is that it is a coadjoint orbit of SU(3) of dimension 6

Comment: The elements of $M$ are the skew-Hermitian matrices. This is indeed a space of dimension $6$.

Comment: I'm sorry I forget to precise  that the entries of  $\lambda$ are differents, and that what makes M of dimension six, I'll fix that

Comment: It was already of dimension $6$. What you done now is removed a Zariski-closed subset of $M$, which doesn't really change anything

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We have $A \cdot B = B$ if and only if $AB = BA$, where $AB$ denotes the matrix product of the matrices $A$ and $B$. Now, consider the specific matrix
$$
A_0 = \pmatrix{-1 \\ & -1\\ && 1} \in T.
$$
If $B$ is any matrix such that $A_0B = BA_0$, what can we say about the matrix $B$? Show that if $B$ is of this required form, then we have $AB = BA$ for every matrix $A \in T$.

Then, note that the set $M$ can be nicely characterized with the help of the spectral theorem.